# How to add an extra language input to Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to add extra languages to Android? My current Android phone only supports English and Chinese language input. I would like to have Dutch also, as I can use it for word completion. The question on top of that is, how to switch easily between these languages in the text input (keyboard) GUI?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On android 2.2 you can input multiple language and switch by sliding on the spacebar. Go in the settings under "language and keyboard" and then "Android Keyboard", "Input language".

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only answers the second part of the question. Language packs can be installed from the market for extra input methods.

Comment: Can we perform this dynamically ?

Answer (score 17):

Don't agree with post above. I have a Hero with only English available and I want Spanish.

I installed MoreLocale 2, and it has lots of different languages (Dutch among them). I choose Spanish, Sense UI restarted and EVERYTHING in my phone changed to Spanish: menus, settings, etc. The keyboard predictive text defaulted to Spanish and started suggesting words in Spanish. This means, somewhere within the OS there is a Spanish dictionary hidden and MoreLocale made it available.

The problem is that English is still the only option available in keyboard input language so I can switch to English but can't switch back to Spanish unless I restart Sense UI, which takes a couple of minutes so not a very practical solution.

Still looking for an easier way to do it.

Comment: You could install http://www.swiftkey.net - you can have prediction in more then one language without changing anything (and use it in one sentence). However the system dictionary will still shows words in other language as misspelled - I switched it off.

Answer (score 1):

Sliding the space bar only works if you gave more then one input language selected.

In that case the space bar will also indicate the selected language and show arrows to indicate Sliding will change selection.

This is easy fast and changes the dictionary at the same time.

First response seems the mist accurate.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I just found Scandinavian Keyboard as a fine solution to this problem. It do also have English and German keyboard, but neither Dutch nor Spanish - but I guess they could be added. And I guess there is other alternatives out there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about sliding the space bar.  I have a small box on the left of my keyboard that indicates which language is selected ( when english is selected it shows the words EN with a small microphone on top.  Being that I also have spanish as one of my languages, I just tap that button and it swithces back and forth from spanish to english.