# Option to see the text in different language in android?

Tags: android, language-agnostic, unicode

**I am working on an application in which i want to give the three language options to the user like English ,Hindi and Punjabi(Regional language).**

*I want to know that what is the best possible way to do that ?* **One way which i find is** to make the Three different xml files of the English, Hindi and Punjabi. Then parse these xml files. I already know how can we show the Punjabi font in android. But i have to use the 4-5 books in my application. So that way look inappropriate.

**Also i have to add the Bookmark feature in my app. So can any one suggest me the best way to use the different books in three languages from where the addition of bookmark feature is also easy.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a research assistant, please post a specific **programming related** problem you are encountering.

Comment: Ok i will edit my question @JoxTraex

Comment: have a look on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963340/how-to-add-an-extra-language-input-to-android and see this tutorial http://www.chayx.net/2011/04/android-phones-east-asian-language-support.html Best of luck

Comment: see if you can use google translate api, if it is working then its easy to implement with translate api, and you can use google translate app too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325547/how-to-have-a-translation-service-in-android-app

Comment: @mak_just4anything no i want to do without google translate api.

Comment: see link there is are many options else try this. http://code.google.com/p/android-translate-api/

Answer (score 1):

Store each version as a raw resource (in /res/raw). Get it out with

```
public static String getRawFile(int resourceId, Resources resources) {

    Writer writer;

    try {
        InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(resourceId);
        writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to read raw resource!", ex);
        return null;
    }

    return writer.toString();
}
```

called like this:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
String text = Utilities.getRawFile(R.raw.test_response, resources));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best answer is to follow the android documentation for [supporting multiple languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) Here is the list of [ISO 639-1 Codes](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) So your project would look something like this:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-pa/
           strings.xml
       values-hi/
           strings.xml
```

Then each strings.xml would have the different values for each language. That would cover things in your user interface and things like that.

Then based on your question if this is some kind of reader you would download the xml file/book that would be appropriate for the users language settings.

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```