# How to add another language to android keyboard?

Tags: android

There is similar question with no answers. I'd like to use 2 languages for typing messages on my Android device. On my Windows phone it seems very easy to add another language to keyboard and switch between them - tap a key and change the keyboard language. How to do the same on Android please? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on Android StackExchange

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963340/how-to-add-an-extra-language-input-to-android

Comment: Sorry, did not know that Android StackExchange exists. Thank you.

Comment: Think of this as a "flag post", as someone can see where to look for this question next time. Also, your question was answered, so it is a win-win :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- open Settings

2- go to Language & input

3- go to Android keyboard

4- go to Languages

5- disable "Use system language" then select your language

6- now open any application you can type on it when keyboard opens you should see a circle like world when select it the language change.

hope this helpful.